# how do you make something happen if a button is pressed in applescript

Tags: button, applescript, volume

I am trying to make an app in applescript where if you try to turn the volume down the volume is set to 16. I am still a beginner and i was wondering if there is a 'if buttonpress' sort of command. Thanks!

Comment: What button are you referring to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I'm understanding you, this is the basic idea:

```
set button_returned to button returned of (display dialog "hi")

if button_returned is "OK" then
    #do something
end if
```

You put up a dialog, then check for the name of the button clicked, and if the name matches whichever button you're checking for, then "do something".